# What software solution can I use (on Windows 10) to keep all my non-Microsoft software up to date?

Tags: windows, package-manager

In other words, is there a Windows 10 equivalent to apt-get / rpm / brew? Preferably cheap or free, and available for use in my business?

The more software packages it supports, the better. Preferably on the order of thousands of different programs supported.

Comment: free.Kaspersky.com has a tool to scan and update almost all your installed apps

Answer (score 76):

UPDATE 2016-10-10: It's possible that Chocolatey version 0.10.0 gave me a malware infection a couple of months ago. However, that does not seem to be the case. I have not had any trouble so far with Chocolatey v0.10.1 or 0.10.3. See further notes in the Comments section.

END UPDATE

I recently discovered Chocolatey: https://chocolatey.org. This is what I am using at the moment.

This is a command-line tool. It requires administrative privileges (naturally). After I installed it, I ran the following commands, among others, to install various applications and register them with Chocolatey:

```
choco install 7zip
choco install firefox
choco install adblockplus-firefox
choco install GoogleChrome
choco install adblockpluschrome
choco install opera
choco install adblockplusopera
choco install git
choco install github
choco install notepadplusplus
choco install SublimeText2
choco install vlc
```

Now, any time I want to check for updates to any of these, and automatically install any updates found, I just run:

`choco upgrade all`

or

`choco upgrade all -y` (to accept all upgrade confirmations)

Works like a charm.

Comment: There's a GUI too: https://chocolatey.org/packages/ChocolateyGUI

Comment: Sometimes the package installed by chocolatey can be [outdated compared to the upstream source](https://chocolatey.org/docs/package-triage-process#package-is-outdated), but often this is resolved after a few days.

Comment: As with any distro & public software repository system, it is valuable to think about what verification is done and what integrity guarantees are provided. Lots of info about Chocolatey security at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Security .  They point out that their commercial offerings have some added commercial virus/malware scanning.

Comment: It also integrates with Windows 10 PackageManager too http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AptGetForWindowsOneGetAndChocolateyOnWindows10.aspx

Comment: It does a virus check, alright. But how about toolbars and all that kind of stuff?

Comment: @Aron Yes. I tried this integration initially, but I ran into some technical glitches. Evidently PackageManagement + Chocolatey isn't quite ready for prime time. Or wasn't when I tried it, in early June.

Comment: @Mathlight I haven't seen Chocolatey install any toolbars or bloatware that I didn't specifically request.

Comment: So at least one of my Win10 machines definitely ended up with a rootkit on it, according to the [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/) scan I ran a few days after the Chocolatey 0.10.0 update. The fact that the "System" process was maxing out one CPU core, as well as the hard drive, on several successive reboots, points to the same conclusion.

The only question is how this happened, and whether any of it was Chocolatey's fault. There is a distinct possibility that my machines were **already** infected before I ever installed Chocolatey. However, if they were, the signs were a lot less obvious.

Comment: My main antivirus program is Webroot SecureAnywhere. As far as I can tell, the file that it flagged as malware was a compressed version of 7z.exe (command-line 7-Zip). The file had a different checksum because the Chocolatey folks had compressed it. At least, that's what they told me. The VirusTotal results for this file are [here](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/a55a7d62665100a623a4b97a09452c6b48347a099a5013c05ff954665c5903b7/analysis/).

Chocolatey release 0.10.1 uncompresses this file, so its checksum now matches the original. And Webroot no longer picks it up as malware.

Comment: I have switched to running only Ubuntu on both my physical machines. I am now running Windows only under VirtualBox VMs. Windows 7 Professional on one; Windows 10 Pro on the other.

I have installed Windows from scratch on each of these machines, taking care to keep them as clean as possible. I ran several malware and rootkit scans before and after installing Chocolatey on each, as well as monitoring the "System" CPU/disk usage before and after. Everything looks OK so far.

Comment: Chocolatey has also tightened up security on its packages. It now makes sure to validate the checksum of each binary EXE downloaded from a third-party website (as most choco packages seem to do). So it would seem that overall, choco security is improving.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what happened, but I will continue to run Chocolatey on my VMs, with a subset of the packages I had installed before, and see if I have any further trouble with it.

Comment: You can judge for yourself whether you think Choco is trustworthy or not. At this point, I have tentatively concluded that it is.

Answer (score 33):

There is in fact a command-line package manager built into Windows 10: **[PackageManagement](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget#what-is-packagemanagement-oneget)**.

It uses PowerShell's extremely verbose language to give a native Windows equivalent of **apt-get** or **yum**. You can start with:

> PS C:> Get-Command -module PackageManagement | sort noun, verb

to generate a list of available commands. There are many other commands and options available, which can be found by following [Microsoft's PackageManager blog entry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/packagemanagement/2015/04/28/introducing-packagemanagement-in-windows-10/) on TechNet. Actual usage is as simple as invoking the following from a PowerShell window:

> PS C:> install-package chrome

There is also an open-source fork of this, called OneGet (which was also the development name of PackageManagement). You can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/OneGet). I believe there's also a PackageManagement plug-in for **Chocolatey**, as well as other package managers, allowing you to install all of *their* packages via PackageManagement too.

Comment: *Extremely verbose* is an understatement...

Comment: `Get-Command -Module PackageManagement` -> `gcm -m package*`

Answer (score 17):

Just my two cents: [Ninite](https://ninite.com/)

It has got a wide variety of apps to choose from, which it will install / update without Toolbars and all that stuff:

[image: List of apps available from Ninite]

Through a simple cmd script, you can set the install language for the apps (If you don't want the default os installed language)

It is also useful for getting all your usual programs on a fresh install of windows.

Comment: Thanks. I have used Ninite a little bit. It's cool and all, just doesn't support the full range of apps I want to keep updated. But many people will probably find it useful.

Answer (score 11):

I used to do computer maintenance kind of work, which required me:

1. To have a lot of setup packages on hand and updated
2. Being able to quickly install/update any/set of them
3. To have a set of portable tools runnable from flash drive and also kept updated

I settled on [Ketarin](http://ketarin.canneverbe.com/), which I still use to this day. It specializes on (1) of updating setup packages, but has plenty of functionality related to scripted installs.

[image: ketarin interface]

It's more on the DIY side of things for configuration, but doesn't rely on any central repository. It can handle complicated downloads when site tries to make that hard.

There are (old) reviews of [Ketarin itself](https://www.rarst.net/software/ketarin/) and [install functionality](https://www.rarst.net/software/ketarin-software-install/) at my blog.

Comment: Ketarin sounds interesting. But when I went to its website, it specifically said that Ketarin is not designed to keep your system up to date. So I don't really think this is what I'm after.

Comment: It can keep install instructions with every application and it can run them (including whenever package updates). As for me this is quite sufficient functionality for that.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Patch My PC Updater](https://patchmypc.net/download):

- free
- update third-party applications
- portable
- light (401 KB for the current version)
- support about 100 applications

[image]

[image: 7]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something that supports a much wider range of software products. I believe Chocolatey supports over 1000 different applications.

For many people, however, Patch My PC might work just fine.

Comment: @StephenGTuggy But it requires the user to have installed the software through Chocolatey, right?

Comment: Sort of. IIRC, it's possible to install a program (say, Firefox) without using Chocolatey, but then run `choco install firefox` to, in effect, "register" Firefox with the Chocolatey system. This command will also install the latest version of Firefox at the same time, if a later version is available.

Comment: @StephenGTuggy Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Flexera (previously Secunia) PSI](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/software-vulnerability-management/personal-software-inspector/):

> #### Stay secure by updating insecure programs on your computer
>
> Personal Software Inspector is a free computer security solution that identifies vulnerabilities in applications on your private PC. Vulnerable programs can leave your PC open to attacks, against which your antivirus solution may not be effective. Simply put, it scans software on your system and identifies programs in need of security updates to safeguard your PC against cybercriminals. It then supplies your computer with the necessary software security updates to keep it safe.
>
> Personal Software Inspector is a security scanner which identifies programs that are insecure and need updates. It automates the updating of the majority of these programs, making it a lot easier to maintain a secure PC. It automatically detects insecure programs, downloads the required patches, and installs them accordingly without further user interaction.
>
> Personal Software Inspector also detects and notifies you of programs that cannot be automatically updated with software patches and provides you with detailed instructions for updating the program when available. In most cases, you simply need to click the appropriate icon in the Results window and follow the on-screen instructions to install the latest patches.
>
> Personal Security Inspector includes the following:
>
> - **Automatic update of programs**: Automatically updates your insecure programs, so you don’t have to visit different software vendor sites and figure out what their particular update mechanism is. On a typical private PC, you have to master between 25 to 30 different update mechanisms to patch approximately 75 programs, if you do not have an automated solution.
> - **Available in 8 languages**: English, French, German, Spanish, Arabic, Danish, Norwegian and Dutch. Because understanding the instructions and recommendations is an important aspect of security.
> - **Covers programs from thousands of vendors**: Includes hundreds of preconfigured software patches for easy deployment and covers 20,000+ programs – more non-Microsoft programs than anyone else.
> - **Integration for deployment**: Personal Software Inspector covers thousands of programs and automatically detects insecure programs, downloads the required patches, and installs them accordingly without further user interaction. The average private PC has around 75 programs installed, so you should be covered.

Comment: Note this only updates on security updates. For example, it didn't offer to update itself.

Comment: I have tried Secunia PSI. I was pretty disappointed with it. The program was CONSTANTLY scanning the software on my PC, and bogging down the system to do it. One warning about an out-of-date software component NEVER WENT AWAY -- for months -- even after I repeatedly installed the update they recommended. Overall, a rather frustrating experience.

Comment: It's dead (well, the good version anyway, the one that tells you what it is doing)   https://secuniaresearch.flexerasoftware.com/community/forum/thread/show/15843/psi_2_0_is_end_of_life_upgrade_to_the_latest_version

Answer (score 2):

[Avast](http://www.avast.com/) (free, Windows) has a module for that, but it doesn't support all applications:

[image]

[image]

Also, if you activate automatic update, it will update without asking you.

[image]

Comment: Again, I'm looking for something that supports a broader range of software. But this feature of Avast! will probably be useful for many other people.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [RuckZuck](https://ruckzuck.codeplex.com/)

[image]

> Select a Software from the Repository and RuckZuck handles the download and the Installation for you.
>   RuckZuck is able to detect and update existing Software that was not installed with RuckZuck.
>
> The RuckZuck repository does not store the binaries of the Software, just the links to where the software is downloaded. Installing Software with RuckZuck does not grant you a license for that Product.

Comment: Hmm. I see RuckZuck offers a OneGet provider, just like Chocolatey does. Cool! Maybe I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For Intel drivers, there is the free [Intel® Driver Update Utility](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?cid=cim:ggl)

[image]

> What components does the tool detect?
>
> Graphic Drivers
>
> The Utility detects Intel® integrated graphics controllers for desktop
> and laptop computers.
>
> If you have an Internet device using the Intel® Graphics Media
> Accelerator 500, go to Intel® Download Center for drivers.
>
> For all other graphics controllers, contact your computer manufacturer
> or place of purchase for drivers support.
>
> Audio Driver for Intel® Desktop Board
>
> The Utility detects audio devices for Intel® Desktop Boards purchased
> through a retailer.
>
> Intel sells desktop boards to computer manufacturers who may customize
> the drivers. These drivers are not detected by this Utility.
>
> Wireless Networking
>
> The Utility detects active Intel® wireless products.
>
> Discontinued products are not detected. Contact your computer
> manufacturer or place of purchase for support.
>
> Wired Networking
>
> The Utility detects Intel® Ethernet network add-in adapters and Intel®
> Desktop Boards with integrated network connections purchased through a
> retailer.
>
> Intel sells wired networking cards to computer manufacturers who may
> customize the drivers. These drivers are supported only by the
> computer manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [FileHippo](http://filehippo.com). The site offers a wide range of applications for download and has a [FileHippo App Manager](http://filehippo.com/download_app_manager/) to keep track of the softwares and update them.

> FileHippo App Manager is a great application that will keep your system up-to-date. FileHippo App Manager will scan your computer for installed applications, check the versions and then send this data to FileHippo.com to ascertain if there are any newer releases available. If there are any new releases, these are then neatly displayed in your browser window for you to download*.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't sound as automated as I would like.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [SuMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) (Software Update Monitor) and [DuMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?page=dumo&showads) (Driver Update Monitor) from KC Software.

- Both are available as a free version and as a paid "Pro" version.
- The number of applications being monitored mainly depends on the number os users using Sumo/DuMo. AFAIK, it will only point you to a new version if at least one user has installed a newer version.

  This on its own is already a downside, but there's one more: some developers may use it while they're working on a newer version of the software. That developer version may be reported as a new version, but the new version is not available for download yet.

Other than that, I'm a quite happy user of it (on Windows 7, however).

Comment: Stable software only, please! As much as possible, anyway.

Comment: @StephenGTuggy: how is it instable?

Comment: I was talking about the third-party software updates that SuMo offers, not about SuMo itself. You said: "some developers may use it while they're working on a newer version of the software. That developer version may be reported as a new version, but the new version is not available for download yet."

Comment: Did I misunderstand? Does SuMo not actually allow you to download these beta versions, or whatever you want to call them?

Comment: @StephenGTuggy: ok, I see. In such a case, SuMo will report an available update and guide you to the webpage for downloading a new version. If the developer has not published that version, you won't find a newer version for download.

Answer (score 0):

2023 update: [WinGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) is now a viable alternative as well. A coworker got me started using it. I am now using both WinGet and Chocolatey to check for updates on the same machine. Sometimes Chocolatey has the latest version of something a day or two before WinGet does. Other times, it's the other way around.

I still generally prefer the no-frills, no-nonsense settings that Chocolatey install scripts tend to use. And the automation. WinGet installs tend to be a bit more interactive. But for some programs, and in some cases, WinGet is better.

Worth noting that WinGet comes with Windows 11, already installed. (As far as I can tell, anyway.)

Compare the Chocolatey "update everything" command:

```
choco upgrade all
```

with the WinGet "check for updates" command:

```
winget upgrade
```

I use them both on almost a daily basis. Note also that the `winget upgrade` command does not need to be run from an elevated PowerShell or Command Prompt window (unlike `choco upgrade all`). The individual installers called by WinGet will ask for elevated permissions as necessary.